# What is the right way to generate Nonce in Google Play Integrity

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

Google has introduced Play Integrity for device verification.

It uses nonce as an input string.
There is no sample on how to generate nonce.
There are few blogs like [these](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/boost-security-of-your-app-with-nonce.html) but there is no example for that can works at production level.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question:
Generate Nonce like this

```
    var nonceBytes = ByteArray(40) //you can change the length
    SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonceBytes)  //randomise the bytes
    var nonce = Base64.encodeToString(nonceBytes,  Base64.URL_SAFE)
```

Hope this helps.